# getting mysql affected rows in shell script variable

Tags: mysql, shell

Here is my shell script which calls some procedure

```
#!/bin/bash
ip=$1
username=$2
password=$3
user=$4

mysql -h $ip -u $username -p$password << EOF

use myDb;

call clear_user_device("$user");

EOF
echo "device cleared successfully"
```

I want- whether rows are affected or not, to show output to user. I tried mysql_affected_rows(), row_count() etc but its not working.

Please help